# Tracing a memory address in Java

Tags: java

How to trace a memory address for a variable in java?
For example in c,c++ we can use pointers or  & or * symbol for a address of a variable. 
Like this in java what we can use for tracing a address for a variable

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea.. Not even sure it is possible in Java. Why do you need this?

Comment: Nothing just to know whether it is possible or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible in java. For more information check the following link.

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091221191211AAHWHb4